# IE 9 background image position attribute

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm new to CSS, trying to display an image through with following code, it works in Chrome and FireFox but not in IE 9. When I remove position attribute, it shows image in IE9. Any help is appreciated !

```
<div style="background:url(/templates/intranet/images/car.png); background-position:50%; background-size:auto 70%; background-repeat:no-repeat;width:100%; height:100%;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: I added top:0; left:0; but didn't work

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="background:url(/templates/intranet/images/car.png); background-position:50% 50%; background-size:auto 70%; background-repeat:no-repeat;width:100%; height:100%;position:absolute;"></div>
```

you have to add "background-position:50% 50%;" to write right css.